# Blackberry application showing Server Authentication Failed when try to call web service or connect to any server

Tags: networking, blackberry

I have problem in my Blackberry application.Actually I have developed a Blackberry chat application using third party server for instant messaging and also some code for webservice calls.

The app is working fine on WIFI network but when I try to run the app on **Carrier Network** it shows

**Server Authentication Failed**

Here is the code for **ConnectionString:**

```
    public static String getConnectionString() {
    String connectionString = "";

    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
    if (USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR) {
    connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    } else {
    connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    }
    }

    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
    String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();
    if (carrierUid == null) {
    // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS. So use the carrier's TCP
    // network
    connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    } else {
    connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID=" + carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
    }
    }
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
    connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    }
    else if (CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) {
    }
    else {
    connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    }
    if ((RadioInfo.getActiveWAFs() & RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN) != 0
    && WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
    connectionString += ";interface=wifi";
    }
    connectionString += ";ConnectionTimeout=30000";
    return connectionString;
    }
```

Here is the code for get **BIS carrier**:

```
public static String getCarrierBIBSUid() {
    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;
    try{
    for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) {
    if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp")) {
    if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0) {
    return records[currentRecord].getUid();
    }
    }
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Where does it say "Server Authentication Failed" ?  What code are you executing when this happens, and how are you able to see that error message?

Comment: @Mister Smith I am facing this problem on carrier networks.The app is working fine for BIS and WIFI.

Answer (score 2):

You probably do not have the correct suffix for BIS. Have a look at how tricky the code is. There are many things to consider and it's easy to make mistakes. This is how things where done in pre-5.0 times.

Fortunately, now we have [`ConnectionFactory`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html), that makes things much easier.